# NSURL returns Nil Value

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

Here Below is my code

```
NSString *string    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" http://abc.com  /Demo/View.php?drinkId=%@&name=%@&comment=%@&date=%@&rating=%@&    ReqestType=SubmitComment",DrinkId,Name,Comment,Date,Rating];

NSURL *url          = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:string];
```

Here in string there is value but url returns nil.
Can Anyone tell why this happened.

Thanks ....

"This won't work, so here's what I did instead"

```
NSString *string    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/Demo/View.php?drinkId=%@&name=%@&comment=%@&date=%@&rating=%@&ReqestType=SubmitComment",DrinkId,Name,Comment,Date,Rating];

NSURL *url          = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:string];
```

Comment: Glad that my answer helped. Could you help everyone out and mark this question as answered?

Comment: Will U tell me hoe to mark this question as answered?

Comment: You click the grey check mark next to the answer, causing it to turn green.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

NSURL will return nil for URLs that contain illegal chars, like spaces.

Before using your string with `[NSURL URLWithString:]` make sure to escape all the disallowed chars by using `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`.

Here is [the class reference for NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score -1):

Hi All Now My Problem Is solved  here I did a mistake left a blank space before "http".

The correct code is

```
NSString *string    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver.com/Demo/View.php?drinkId=%@&name=%@&comment=%@&date=%@&rating=%@&ReqestType=SubmitComment",DrinkId,Name,Comment,Date,Rating];

NSURL *url          = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:string];
```