# Remove string with special character Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string (IN)+91 but I want to get only +91 and remove characters within `()`, i.e `(IN)`. How to do it in iOS with objective-c ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Choice - 1**

```
NSString *final=@"(IN)+91";
NSArray *tempArray = [final componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
final = [tempArray lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", final);
```

**Choice - 2**

```
NSRange range1 = [final rangeOfString:@")" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *newString = [final substringFromIndex:(range1.location+1)];
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Comment: Thanks to all, 
 Anbu and KAR my task has been done Thank you

Comment: @puja - welcome mate...

Comment: hey i have one more issue, will you help me out?

Comment: @puja - what the issue

Comment: i am passing +91 8401156898 as a data to my api 
using NSData *postData = [strBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; in this it removes + sign from string and in my database i want with +
do you have any idea?

Comment: @puja - initially remove space there after use NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: @puja - SEE THIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258940/nsurl-returns-nil-value

Comment: its same in my db it removes + sign , i dont know why this happens

Comment: @puja - ARE YOU SEEN THE LINK

Comment: yes i have seen and tried that NSUTF8StringEncoding but in database it removed that + sign and i want it to store in my db

Comment: i have got the solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085533/adding-before-using-2b-using-url-encoding-in-iphone
its Done ,Thanks

Comment: @puja - its is the alternate way. anyway congrtz...

Comment: yes you are correct but right now i don't have that much time its urgent btw Thanks

Comment: @puja - welcome mate , accept any one answer, it is useful in future

Comment: sure i will do the same @Anbu, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
    NSString *myString = @"(IN)+91";
    NSArray *subStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
    NSString *firstString = [subStrings objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *lastString = [subStrings objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"first - %@, second - %@", firstString, lastString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex to replace all matched text at once

```
NSError *error;
NSString *pattern = @"\([^\)]*\)";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *afterText = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:beforeText options:0 range:range withTemplate:@""];
```